# Calculating time interval for one day by joining tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a beginner in Postgres. I'm still learning by mostly solving problems.

I have a PostgreSQL database with two tables: `trips`, which contains information about each trip a vehicle has taken, and `gps_points`, which contains the GPS points covered on each trip.

The trips table contains the columns [id, start_time, end_time, vehicle_id]. The gps_points table contains the columns [id, trip_id, latitude, longitude].

How do I write a query to select the GPS points (latitude and longitude) covered by vehicle number 4 on trips which were fully contained on the 1st January 2018 (i.e. both started and ended on that date).

Comment: I think you have forgotten to ask a question.  Sample data and desired results would also be a big help.

Comment: the key parts of your question are not really distinct and reusable, please define code blocks and provide some data to represent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
select p.latitude
     , p.longitude
  from trips t
  join gps_points p
    on p.trip_id = t.id
 where t.vehicle_id = 4
   and date_trunc('day', t.start_time) = date '2018-01-01'
   and date_trunc('day', t.end_time) = date '2018-01-01'
```